# Unable to connect to openfire server using SSL port from Strophe.js

Tags: ssl, xmpp, openfire, strophe

I use Strophe library to connect to an OpenFire XMPP server.
I am unable to connect to openfire server using SSL port.
I am using the http-bind url as 
https://localhost:7443/http-bind/ 
for connecting to openfire server.

Do I need to configure anything in Openfire server ?

Comment: Did you installed an ssl certificate?

Comment: SSL certificate is added by default localhost (localhost_rsa) in Server Certificates during the Openfire server installation.

Comment: There are not generated by a certification auithority, there are self signed.

Comment: Can you please guide me in generating a new self signed certificate

Comment: You should also add this in server properties xmpp.socket.ssl.active
true